# Taxonomy in multilingual environment

Tags: content-management-system, multilingual, taxonomy, kentico-kontent, content-model

How to organize a list of content items (i.e. projects in portfolio) into different categories (i.e. industries) in [Kentico Cloud](https://kenticocloud.com/) content as a service platform.

i.e.

- Project 1 (content type project) - Commercial (industry)
- Project 2 (content type project) - Commercial (industry)
- Project 3 (content type project) - Health care (industry)

There are two solutions on the table:

1. Create a content type called industries and ad linked items element called industries to the project content type
2. Create a taxonomy group, called industries and tag the content item "client" with a tag

Our dev favored option 2, however, it seems not to be possible to localize a tag value and it would therefore never be possible to display the tag itself in the multilingual UI.

What would the official recommendation for this?

> This question is a migrated from official Kentico Cloud Forum, that would be deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When designing multilingual support for Kentico Cloud, localization of taxonomy groups was designed that way as well. 
It is still in the plan to do it in the future, but as many other priorities arrive, **multilingual support for taxonomy terms is currently postponed**.

According to the question - there is no constraint to model taxonomy just using [taxonomy groups](https://developer.kenticocloud.com/v1/reference#taxonomy-group-object).

**The best way to model this use case is to use [linked items elements](https://developer.kenticocloud.com/v1/reference#linked-content) functionality** as it is in [example](https://developer.kenticocloud.com/docs/linking-content-together#section-2-add-a-place-to-link-authors-in-your-articles). It supports multilingual and it could be used for categorization. And it is also possible to limit the element to allow placing only one content type (industry in your case).